# showing actual printer image of a printer in devices and printers in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, printer

My printer's device driver have the actual colorful image(i see it in preferences of printer) of the printer(not the windows default image for the printer). How can i make it display in the devices & printers window? I see the picture of my walkman and ipod when i connect to the computer.

Please see the attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those images are controlled by the drivers. The only way to get the image to change is to install a driver for the device that comes with the correct image, which would require the device manufacturer to do it.